# android sdk. Background image fits. Foreground images too small

Tags: android, image, android-2.2-froyo

I have my view built to fit a phone screen 800x480.  The background PNG shows up as a perfect fit.  I have a bunch of imageViews of PNGs sitting on the view that should line up perfectly on any screen that is that size.
When tested on my phone, it works fine.  However, when tested on my 7" tablet that has the same screen resolution, the backdrop fits as expected, but the imageViews are all too small.

Why wouldn't they fit the same way, considering the resolution is the same?

Comment: Actually, resolution in not a criterion in Android layouts. When you use some drawable (e.g. png) Android system first makes your layout and views the size it thinks they should have and only after it adds images. 
Please post layout file.

Comment: I can see where resolution should be an issue, like, if you have something that is 2" on one resolution, would look different at another.  lke 72dpi vs 180dpi.  But if the pixel size is the same, the inches/res shouldn't matter.  I'll post screen grabs of both devices later.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the aspect ratio of the second screen?

I know that when I developed an app on my Note I, it showed up differently on almost every other device with the same resolution, on account of the aspect ratio of the Note I being so wide.

Can you check and see the actual pixel ratio of your second device?

Also, is it showing the on screen action bar thing? The back/menu/etc bit? Because that could be because of the version you're targeting is less than the version of your 7" device, causing it to run in backwards compatibility mode. That'll squish your layout a bit as well.

Comment: There is a title bar, and nothing more. The nav control for both devices is outside the layout.
As far as ascpect ratio, they are both 800x480.  Same ratio.  Even if the inch dimensions of the screens are different ratio, the pixel ratio is the same.

Comment: are you using absolute px for sizes, or are you using dp?

Comment: Uh. I hope it's not as simple as that. Then I will feel like I wasted everyone's time. I never defined the sizes. I just have the view containers set as "wrap_content". I was under the impression that that setting always simply expands the imageView container to hold whatever you put in there. And it does. On the phone device. It may well be that the other device is not seeing the size of the images the same way. I'll have to give that a shot.

Comment: How are the view containers themselves positioned? Could you take a couple screenshots of what you're talking about and put it in your question to make it a bit easier for us?

Comment: I would post, but I don't have the code on this machine.  But I can tell you this...  The layout is done with relative postioning like, android:_layoutBelow:"this", layout_toTheRightOf:"this", and so on.  The positioning is just fine with both devices. The entire grid that I've created is laying out perfectly, but like 25% smaller on the larger device.

Comment: And for what it's worth, you've already given me one really good idea to follow up on.  I'll try that when I get hope and post my findings later.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer to this.
I couldn't find a way to set the size of the PNG itself.  Only the ImageView height and width.  So I set those to 90dp.  I tried px first.  Don't do that.  It's no good.
But, check this out...  Forcing the size in dp made the images show correctly on the tablet, but enormous on the phone!  So, it more or less reversed my problem.

But at least I know what the problem is now.  I just have to create a secondary view for 7" screens to set the imageView sizes.  Or, I'm thinking there must be a way to do this problematically.  Before the view launches, detect the screen size, if it's not a phone, change the height and width accordingly.

That should work because, as I mentioned in an earlier comment, the relative positioning is perfect.  It's just the size that's incorrect.

Comment: Following up on this, for anyone interested.  The solution to the problem was to specify the height and width for the imageViews.  Since this doesn't work evenly for all devices, I created a separate view for larger screens.  This works perfectly, and I didn't need to change any of the code, other than to detect the screen size and show one view or the other.